# How to make multiple query in php using checkbox?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am building a simple app whose basic task is to approve the content listed from a MySQL table. List items are long, like 15 to 20 items. I want to place a check-box right to the list items and allow the users to check multiple items and click submit button to approve selected items.

I have made a basic flag column on the table to set 0 or 1 for approve or disapprove. In my existing system user has to click the link and go to the particular page and click approve to approve the item.I want to shorten the process by allowing the users to check the check-box and select multiple entry to approve those items at one time.

[image]

this is my table and the item is YouTube link so the admin can view the video and if it good he/she can approve it by checking the check-box.

here is the php code for the current page specific to approve the item

```
<?php 
$msg = "";
$idForm = $_GET['id'];

if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){
    $msg= approveVideo($idForm);
}
?>
```

the approveVideo function:

```
function approveVideo($id) {
    $message ="";
    $query= "UPDATE locus_videos SET set_flag='1' WHERE id='{$id}'";

    if(mysql_query($query)) {
        $message ="Video Approved ";
    }else {
        die("failed: " . mysql_error());    
    }

    return $message;

}
```

The Table format for the php file:

```
<table width="100%" height="487" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
```

" method="POST">

```
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
```

Uploader Name
    Video Link

">
    
    
    " target="_blank">

```
  </form>
</td>
```

In my current version when the user click the link of the video this redirect to the specific page and from there only he can approve the video (the YouTube link)

Comment: have you written any PHP at all for this project?  If so, please show the relevant parts.  If not, then you might look for some basic PHP + HTML form tutorials.

Comment: that's a screenshot from phpmyadmin

Comment: @mishu I think this is an example of what he's trying to do

Comment: I think inspecting the source of the example will show the first step as using names like field_name[] to post arrays

Comment: i have edited the content and now you can see my current php codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways, depending if you just want to "approve" rows, or "approve" and "disapprove" rows.

First:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Url</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="Approve[]" value="1" /></td>
            <td>http://www.youtube.com/...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="Approve[]" value="2" /></td>
            <td>http://www.youtube.com/...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="Approve[]" value="3" /></td>
            <td>http://www.youtube.com/...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, there is a checkbox with the name "Approve[]" and a different Value for each row. The value is the ID column of your table.

Within your PHP, you would then use the following:

```
function approveVideos($ids)
{
    $message = '';
    $query = 'update locus_videos set set_flag = 1 where id in (' . implode(',', $ids) . ')';
    if(mysql_query($query)) 
    {
        $message ="Videos Approved ";
    }
    else 
    {
        die("failed: " . mysql_error());    
    }
    return $message;
}


$ids = $_POST['Approve'];
approveVideos($ids);
```

Second:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Url</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="Approve[1]" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" name="Approve[1]" value="1" /></td>
            <td>http://www.youtube.com/...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="Approve[2]" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" name="Approve[2]" value="1" /></td>
            <td>http://www.youtube.com/...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="Approve[3]" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" name="Approve[3]" value="1" /></td>
            <td>http://www.youtube.com/...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Within the PHP, you would do the following:

```
function setVideoFlag($id, $flag = 1)
{
    $message = '';
    $query = 'update locus_videos set set_flag = ' . $flag . ' where id = ' . $id;
    if(mysql_query($query)) 
    {
        $message ="Video " . ($flag == 1 ? 'Approved' : 'Disapproved');
    }
    else 
    {
        die("failed: " . mysql_error());    
    }
    return $message;
}

foreach($_POST['Approve'] as $id => $flag)
{
    setVideoFlag($id, $flag);
}
```

I hope that helps?

Gavin

Answer (score 2):

Fairly easy. You need an array of checkboxes (below) for each of your content you'd like to approve. Put in the value of each checkbox as the content id

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_1" name="**band[]**" value="ABC" /> ABC <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_2" name="**band[]**" value="PQR" /> PQR <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_3" name="**band[]**" value="XYZ" /> XYZ <br/>
```

Now the above checkboxes will be encapsulated in your . when you SUBMIT the form and check the POSTed array (viz. $_POST) it will have entries as

Array (
    "band" => Array(
          "0" => ABC, 1 => PQR.
    ); 
);

Use php's implode function to convert this to a comma-delimited php string and pass this string to the IN clause of your Update query's WHERE.

Two things are important.

1) You'd need to use array of checkboxes as I used in the above sample.

2) You need to set the value attribute of the checkboxes to the content id or whatever is the primary key of your content table. Hope this helps.

Comment: these return values are the id numbers so do i have to put them inside the id like 

WHERE id='1,2,3'

Comment: Nope. WHERE id IN (1,2,3). Try Gavin's solution, though cause its in sync with your code/implementation.